# How to Migrate from activity to fragment

Tags: android, fragment, mvvmcross

I'm migrating an activity to a fragment. The fragment will ultimately be placed in a tab page.

I have copied the "grouped list" from the Conference example. The listview was on an activity. I am now moving same to a fragment. The method `OnViewModelSet()` does not exist in the view. Where am I supposed to moved the code contained in `OnViewModelSet()` when using a fragment?

Comment: Guess this question is related (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898760/mvvmcross-polymorphic-list-within-fragment-based-tab-view) but still no definite answer.

Comment: Seems I also need the Context to pass to the list adapter, and there is no context in the fragment.

Comment: Basically I am looking for an example where a grouped listview is on a fragment, and that fragment is itself placed on a tab page fragment.

Comment: I don't think you will receive any definite answer. You should just try it. Fragments are useful, but a bit difficult to use right. Setting up the big picture and getting something that works isn't so difficult, but afterwards you will face new problems like fragment life cycle, backstacks, etc. That's the way fragment programming is, you are leaving the safe shores of the Activity world  for the wild one of reusable UI elements. Go ahead and repost if you have troubles.

Comment: I believe I was not clear enough, this post is related to MVVMCross only.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://prezi.com/fh2uslbr1xs3/the-fragment-transition/) is a very good talk on this topic by Corey Latislaw. She gave it at DroidCon London 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Extends your class from fragment instead of activity and call fragment class functions with the view.

I suggest you to please upload some piece of code.

Comment: As per my last comment, the Conference example is the starting point. How to convert the grouped listview, which is an activity in itself, into a fragment, which lies onto a tab page fragment.